# Need to use ToString method to print triangles with *

Tags: c#, tostring

I am trying to figure out how to display with the ToString method the triangles I have made using the * symbol in nested for loops. I have a decent understanding of the ToString method but I have no idea how to actually go about using for loops in a return value.

```
using System;

public class Triangle
{
    public static void Main(string[ ] args)
    {
        Object obj = new Object( );
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString( ));
    }

    public override string ToString( )
    {
        for(int row = 1; row <= 10; ++row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine( );
        }

        Console.WriteLine( );

        for(int row = 10; row >= 1; --row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine( );
        }

        Console.WriteLine( );

        for(int row = 10; row >= 1; --row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine( );
        }

        Console.WriteLine( );

        for(int row = 1; row <= 10; ++row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine( );
        }
        return x;
        Console.ReadKey( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you create a new `Triangle`, not a new `Object`?  Also just use a `StringBuilder` instead of `Console.Write` and return the `ToString` of that.  Or don't use an overload of `ToString`, just make it a void method you call that writes to the console.

Comment: I'm assuming your doing this for a homework assignment, so I'm not going to write it for you.  You need to build a triangle string and return the string.  Another hint your technically building the string already, just using console.write instead using the method to build the string.

Comment: You should separate your `Triangle` class from the `Program` class (which contains the `Main` method). Then instantiate a new `Triangle` (instead of an `object`) and write it to the console.

Comment: You should not call `Console.WriteLine` in the `ToString()` method. The method should simply return the string that represents the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Triangle
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( );

    public static void Main(string[ ] args)
    {
        Triangle tri = new Triangle( );

        Console.WriteLine(tri.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey( );
    }

    public override string ToString( )
    {

        for(int row = 1; row <= 10; ++row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                sb.Append("*");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");

        }

        sb.Append("\n");

        for(int row = 10; row >= 1; --row)
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= row; ++col)
            {
                sb.Append("*");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }

        sb.Append("\n");

        for(int row = 10; row >= 1; row--) // Outer Loop for number of rows
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= 10 - row; col++)         //Inner loop for number of spaces
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 1; k <= row; k++)  //Secondary inner loop for number of stars
            {
                sb.Append("*");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");

        }

        sb.Append("\n");

        for(int row = 1; row <= 10; row++)               //Outer Loop for number of rows
        {
            for(int col = 1; col <= 10 - row; col++)         //Inner loop for number of spaces
            {
                sb.Append(" ");
            }
            for(int k = 1; k <= row; k++)  //Secondary inner loop for number of stars
            {
                sb.Append("*");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
        }
        string s = sb.ToString( );

        return s;


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably homework so I wont write the actual answer for you, but I will tell you what your problems are.

1. You are instantiating a `new Object()`, instead of a `new Triangle()`.  `Object` is just the very basic thing all classes inherit from, `Triangle` is actually the custom class you made.  You want to use that.
2. Your `Triangle` class should be in its own file, or at the very least separate from `Program`.  So for example:

```
class Triangle
{
    //override ToString()
}

class Program
{
    //This is where your main method should be
}
```

3. Your `ToString()` method needs to return a string.  Calling a bunch of `Console.WriteLine()` is contrary to what the method should do.  You should use `StringBuilder` or at least concatenate strings to build out your giant triangle string and then return it from the method.

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to create new Triangle object not object

```
Triangle tri= new Triagle();
Console.WriteLine(tri.ToString());
```

2- also you should store the value in some string variable and return it, you're doing console prints!

3- also how you are using Cosole.ReadKey() after return statement.

4- What's that X variable you return

5- There's a simple solution "might be not efficient but it's simple program anyway"

```
let's say your row count is 5
string returnVal = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
  returnVal + ="    *********".Substring(i, 5 + i)+"\n";
return returnVal;
```

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions and help,  I have it working now.